# Absolute URL paths mysteriously broken - Am I doing it Wrong?

Tags: notation, url

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application, and have been for a while.

I often use the ~ notation for my relative urls, so I can use the same code for testing and deployment.

When I'm running localhost I am using `http://localhost:XXXX`

When the system is live the URL pattern is `http://server_name/build_db_name`

Previously, the ~ notation would suffice so `~/Management/Employees` would work fine, but for some unknown reason, this is not the case anymore.

So I am under the impression I've somehow been doing this wrong.

So my question: **What is the most reliable way of constructing relative URLs?**

Comment: use `.` instead of `~`